# Use Table name in SQL query in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

Below is the excel table i want to manipulate via SQL query in VBA.

[image]
Please find my VBA code.

```
Sub SQL()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [Sr] FROM [Table1$] WHERE [Sr] >= 3 AND [Sr] <= 8;"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheet5.Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

I am getting below error for my above code.

[image]

Please guide how can i manipulate excel table in SQL query in VBA.

Comment: That is not Sheet name. That is ListObject's name.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Plase how can i use directly Table name (ListObject's name) in the query..

Comment: Following works `strSQL = "SELECT [Sr] FROM [Sheet1$A1:B15] WHERE [Sr] >= 3 AND [Sr] <= 8"` So issue is near Table1 portion.

Comment: Okay, but what "works" isn't what was asked. Tables don't require you to know the range as they adjust automatically - so this isn't really workable where named tables are used, unless every single query gets updated every time any table adds or removes rows or columns. This is likely to be unacceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Querying the ListObject's range using a table alias will work.

### SQL

> SELECT [Sr] FROM [Sheet1$A1:D15] AS [Table1] WHERE [Sr] >= 3 AND [Sr] <= 8;

### Code

```
Sub SQL()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
             & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    strSQL = "SELECT [Sr] FROM " & getListObjectSQLAdress(Sheet1.ListObjects(1)) & " WHERE [Sr] >= 3 AND [Sr] <= 8;"

    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    Sheet5.Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub

Function getListObjectSQLAdress(tbl As ListObject) As String
    getListObjectSQLAdress = "[" & tbl.Parent.Name & "$" & tbl.Range.Address(False, False) & "] AS [" & tbl.Name & "]"
End Function
```

Alternative method to build a valid SQL Query Table name from a ListObject.Range

```
Function getListObjectSQLAdress2(tbl As ListObject) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = tbl.Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    s = Replace(s, "'[", "`")
    s = Replace(s, "]", "`.[")
    s = Replace(s, "'!", "$")
    getListObjectSQLAdress2 = s & "] AS [" & tbl.Name & "]"
End Function
```

### Table Name Output

```
`Untitled (4).xlsx`.[Sheet1$A1:D15] AS [Table1]
```

Comment: Hi, why not use `tbl.Range.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)` ? this will get you the worksheet's name as well

Comment: The bracketing is wrong and it returns the workbooks name as well.

Comment: @ShaiRado I just appended an alternate function that uses your method.  This method will come in handy if you need to query multiple workbooks in a single statement.